# How do I export a dashboard in Google Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, looker, data-studio-custom-visuals

How do I export a dashboard in Google Looker Studio. I would like to export a subset of the dashboard and move it to a different customer specific Google Account, is there a way to back the dashboard definition in GitHub repo or in a format which can be re-imported